# Convert XPS to SVG

Tags: svg, xps

Is there a direct and fast way to convert [XPS (XML Paper Specification)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification) files to [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format?

I can convert XPS to PDF and then using [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to convert them to SVG.
But the PDF->SVG step is very time consuming though this process seems is not CPU consuming.

My understanding is that be cause XPS is a vector based format, converting it to another vector based format like SVG must be feasible and much faster than converting raster based format (though i'm not entirely sure pdf is just raster base) to vector based formats.

BTW, the goal is to display vector based images in browser, and I've XPS files.

Comment: PDF can directly embed vector graphics and raster graphics…

Comment: Both XPS and PDF may contain a mix of raster and vector content. There's not guarantee that your original XPS content wasn't already mostly raster. Can you provide more context for this scenario? What's the source of the XPS content? What's the eventual usage scenario that requires SVG?

Comment: @Jon Yeah, you are probably right. I'm not sure what's the original source, I suspect it was some text converted to PDF and then converted to Macromedia FlashPaper. from there to XPS. I want to serve SVG to browser with ability to max zoom.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing library that converts from XPS to SVG or are you looking to write one yourself? If you have a good SVG OM lib then converting from XPS using MS's XPS OM to SVG is pretty easy and fast. I have written a converter in the past to take SVG to XPS in that manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[libgxps](https://github.com/GNOME/libgxps) reads XPS and can create SVG files.

I tried it on Cygwin with the `xpstosvg` command and worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried xpstosvg from the answer above to convert an XPS document with about 100 pages. Unfortunately, the tool produced only one large SVG image with about 90 MB file size, which was not exactly what I was looking for, since the file could not be viewed and I needed one image per page.

Also the manual of the program did not give any hint how to get one image per page. In the end I used an [online XPS converter](https://converter.app/xps-to-pdf/), which really created a SVG image for each page.